# Is there any way to use aiohttp client with socks proxy?

Tags: python, aiohttp

Looks like `aiohttp.ProxyConnector` [doesn't](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/connector.py#L639) support socks proxy. Is there any workaround for this? I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: You can try to ask your question in Google group for aio-libs: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/aio-libs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried aiosocks ?

```
import asyncio
import aiosocks
from aiosocks.connector import SocksConnector

conn = SocksConnector(proxy=aiosocks.Socks5Addr(PROXY_ADDRESS, PROXY_PORT), proxy_auth=None, remote_resolve=True)
session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn)
async with session.get('http://python.org') as resp:
    assert resp.status == 200
```

Comment: When I try this, I get `"ImportError: cannot import name 'SocksConnector'"` ... What is correct way to do this now?

Comment: @J.Taylor Use `ProxyConnector` instead. `from aiosocks.connector import ProxyConnector` https://github.com/nibrag/aiosocks#aiohttp-usage

Answer (score 2):

[aiosocks](https://github.com/nibrag/aiosocks) does not work with the newer version 3.+ of aiohttp.
You can use [aiosocksy](https://github.com/romis2012/aiosocksy) to implement socks proxy.

To check whether aiosocksy is working you can look at the following code sample  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53657536/6735546

Comment: While you are correct, `aiohttp-socks` from same developer is more likely to get maintenance in future updates, according to [readme](https://github.com/romis2012/aiohttp-socks#why-yet-another-socks-connector-for-aiohttp).

Comment: as above user mentioned, now `aiohttp-socks` is supported again, and `aiosocksy` was deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

The Correct answer doesn't work anymore.

Import ProxyConnector from aiosocks.connector rather than SocksConnector

```py
import aiohttp
import aiosocks
from aiosocks.connector import ProxyConnector

conn = ProxyConnector(remote_resolve=True)
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn) as session:
    async with session.get("http://python.org", proxy=f"{PROXY_ADDRESS}:{PROXY_PORT}") as resp:
        assert resp.status == 200
```

Answer (score 1):

in new versions, you might try something like this:

```
from aiohttp_socks import ProxyConnector


asyncio_loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
# context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=...)
connector = ProxyConnector.from_url(
    socksProxy,
    # ssl=context,
    loop=asyncio_loop,
    enable_cleanup_closed=True
)
# override session
session = aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=asyncio_loop, connector=connector, trust_env=False)
encoded_body = ({'param1': 'value1'}).encode()
session.get(yarl.URL(url, encoded=True), data=encoded_body, headers=request_headers, timeout=10) as response:
http_response = await response.text(errors='replace')
print(http_response)
```