# How to use SOCKS proxies to make requests with aiohttp?

Tags: python, proxy, python-asyncio, socks, aiohttp

I am trying to use `aiohttp` to make asynchronous HTTP requests over multiple SOCKS proxies. Basically, I am creating a pool of Tor clients with different IP addresses, and want to be able to route HTTP requests through them using `aiohttp`.

Based on the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960800/is-there-any-way-to-use-aiohttp-client-with-socks-proxy/39593429#comment87410374_39593429) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511728/how-can-i-use-socks4-and-socks5-proxies-with-aiohttp-clientsession), I have been trying to use [aiosocks](https://github.com/nibrag/aiosocks), but the examples in those threads do not work (if they ever did) because they are based on an old version of `aiosocks` with a different API. Documentation and examples of using `aiosocks` online are very sparse (it doesn't seem widely used). But I haven't been able to find any other solutions for using `aiohttp` with SOCKS proxies.

Below is the code I have so far (sorry for the large amount of code - I tried to slim down the example as much as I could!). First I initialize the Tor clients with `stem`:

```
from datetime import datetime
import stem.process

from TorUtils import printCircuits, cleanShutdown

NUM_TOR_CLIENTS = 3

# create list of (source_port, control_port) tuples
tor_ports = [(str(9050 + i), str(9050 + NUM_TOR_CLIENTS + i)) for i in range(NUM_TOR_CLIENTS)]

# Every ISO 3166 country code except for {US} and {CA}
country_codes = '{AF}, {AX}, {AL}, {DZ}, {AS}, {AD}, {AO}, {AI}, {AQ}, {AG}, {AR}, {AM}, {AW}, {AU}, {AT}, {AZ}, {BS}, {BH}, {BD}, {BB}, {BY}, {BE}, {BZ}, {BJ}, {BM}, {BT}, {BO}, {BQ}, {BA}, {BW}, {BV}, {BR}, {IO}, {BN}, {BG}, {BF}, {BI}, {KH}, {CM}, {CV}, {KY}, {CF}, {TD}, {CL}, {CN}, {CX}, {CC}, {CO}, {KM}, {CG}, {CD}, {CK}, {CR}, {CI}, {HR}, {CU}, {CW}, {CY}, {CZ}, {DK}, {DJ}, {DM}, {DO}, {EC}, {EG}, {SV}, {GQ}, {ER}, {EE}, {ET}, {FK}, {FO}, {FJ}, {FI}, {FR}, {GF}, {PF}, {TF}, {GA}, {GM}, {GE}, {DE}, {GH}, {GI}, {GR}, {GL}, {GD}, {GP}, {GU}, {GT}, {GG}, {GN}, {GW}, {GY}, {HT}, {HM}, {VA}, {HN}, {HK}, {HU}, {IS}, {IN}, {ID}, {IR}, {IQ}, {IE}, {IM}, {IL}, {IT}, {JM}, {JP}, {JE}, {JO}, {KZ}, {KE}, {KI}, {KP}, {KR}, {KW}, {KG}, {LA}, {LV}, {LB}, {LS}, {LR}, {LY}, {LI}, {LT}, {LU}, {MO}, {MK}, {MG}, {MW}, {MY}, {MV}, {ML}, {MT}, {MH}, {MQ}, {MR}, {MU}, {YT}, {MX}, {FM}, {MD}, {MC}, {MN}, {ME}, {MS}, {MA}, {MZ}, {MM}, {NA}, {NR}, {NP}, {NL}, {NC}, {NZ}, {NI}, {NE}, {NG}, {NU}, {NF}, {MP}, {NO}, {OM}, {PK}, {PW}, {PS}, {PA}, {PG}, {PY}, {PE}, {PH}, {PN}, {PL}, {PT}, {PR}, {QA}, {RE}, {RO}, {RU}, {RW}, {BL}, {SH}, {KN}, {LC}, {MF}, {PM}, {VC}, {WS}, {SM}, {ST}, {SA}, {SN}, {RS}, {SC}, {SL}, {SG}, {SX}, {SK}, {SI}, {SB}, {SO}, {ZA}, {GS}, {SS}, {ES}, {LK}, {SD}, {SR}, {SJ}, {SZ}, {SE}, {CH}, {SY}, {TW}, {TJ}, {TZ}, {TH}, {TL}, {TG}, {TK}, {TO}, {TT}, {TN}, {TR}, {TM}, {TC}, {TV}, {UG}, {UA}, {AE}, {GB}, {UM}, {UY}, {UZ}, {VU}, {VE}, {VN}, {VG}, {VI}, {WF}, {EH}, {YE}, {ZM}, {ZW}'

tor_configs = [{'SOCKSPort': p[0], 'ControlPort': p[1], 'DataDirectory': './.tordata' + p[0], 
    'CookieAuthentication' : '1',  'MaxCircuitDirtiness': '3600', 'ExcludeNodes': country_codes,
    'EntryNodes': '{us}, {ca}', 'ExitNodes': '{us}, {ca}', 'StrictNodes': '1',
    'GeoIPExcludeUnknown': '1', 'EnforceDistinctSubnets': '0'
    } for p in tor_ports]

print(f"Spawning {NUM_TOR_CLIENTS} tor clients ...")
start_time = datetime.now()

tor_clients = []
for cfg in tor_configs:
    tor_clients.append({'config': cfg, 'process': stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(config = cfg)})
```

... and then I am trying to use the following code to make the HTTP requests with `aiohttp`:

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import aiosocks
from aiosocks.connector import ProxyConnector, ProxyClientRequest
import async_timeout

TIMEOUT = 10

async def _get(url, session, proxy, request_limiter):
    try:
        async with request_limiter: # semaphore to limit number of concurrent requests
            async with async_timeout.timeout(TIMEOUT):
                async with session.get(url, proxy=proxy, proxy_auth=None) as resp:

                    status = int(resp.status)
                    headers = dict(resp.headers)
                    content_type = str(resp.content_type)
                    text = await resp.text()

                    return {'url': url, 'status': status, 'headers': headers, 'text': str(text), 'errors': None}

    except asyncio.TimeoutError as e:
        queue.visited_urls[url] = datetime.now()
        return {'url': url, 'status': None, 'headers': None, 'text': None, 'errors': str(e)}


async def _getPagesTasks(url_list, tor_clients, request_limiter, loop):
    """Launch requests for all web pages."""

    #deque rotates continuously through SOCKS sessions for each tor client ...
    sessions = deque()
    for tor_client in tor_clients:
        conn = ProxyConnector()
        session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn, request_class=ProxyClientRequest)
        sessions.append({'proxy': 'http://127.0.0.1:' + tor_client['config']['SOCKSPort'], 'session': session})

    tasks = []
    task_count = 0
    for url in url_list:
        s = sessions.popleft();
        session = s['session']
        proxy = s['proxy']
        task = loop.create_task(_get(url, session, proxy, request_limiter))
        tasks.append(task)
        task_count += 1
        session.append(s)

    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    for s in sessions:
        s.close()

    return results

def getPages(url_list, tor_clients):
    """Given a URL list, dispatch pool of tor clients to concurrently fetch URLs"""

    request_limiter = asyncio.Semaphore(len(tor_clients)) # limit to one request per client at a time

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    responses = loop.run_until_complete(_getPagesTasks(url_list, tor_clients, request_limiter, loop))

    loop.close()
    return responses
```

This code is not running, however. When I try to run it, I get the error below. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong, or if this is some problem with `aiosocks` (which seems like it's been unmaintained for a while, and might be targetting an older version of `aiohttp` or something ...):

```
~/Code/gis project/code/TorGetQueue.py in _getPagesTasks(url_list, tor_clients, request_limiter, loop)
     50     sessions = deque()
     51     for client in tor_clients:
---> 52         conn = ProxyConnector()
     53         session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn, request_class=ProxyClientRequest)
     54         sessions.append({'proxy': 'http://127.0.0.1:' + client['config']['SOCKSPort'], 'session': session})

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/code-pIyQci_2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiosocks/connector.py in __init__(self, verify_ssl, fingerprint, resolve, use_dns_cache, family, ssl_context, local_addr, resolver, keepalive_timeout, force_close, limit, limit_per_host, enable_cleanup_closed, loop, remote_resolve)
     54             force_close=force_close, limit=limit,  loop=loop,
     55             limit_per_host=limit_per_host, use_dns_cache=use_dns_cache,
---> 56             enable_cleanup_closed=enable_cleanup_closed)
     57 
     58         self._remote_resolve = remote_resolve

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'resolve'
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there an easier way to use SOCKS proxies with `aiohttp`? What do I need to change to make this code work with `aiosocks`?

Thanks!

Comment: p.s. I realize that this Tor configuration totally breaks anonymity. It's not important for my application. I'm just using it as a pool of disposable proxies with different IPs.

Answer (score 3):

I tried using aiosocks for my project to get the same error as yours only to later discover that aiosocks has been abandoned.

You can use [aiosocksy](https://github.com/romis2012/aiosocksy) instead.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from aiosocksy import Socks5Auth
from aiosocksy.connector import ProxyConnector, ProxyClientRequest


async def fetch(url):
    connector = ProxyConnector()
    socks = 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector, request_class=ProxyClientRequest) as session:
        async with session.get(url, proxy=socks) as response:
            print(await response.text())


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(fetch('http://httpbin.org/ip'))
```

Comment: DEPRECATED: please use new aiohttp-socks package: https://github.com/romis2012/aiohttp-socks

Answer (score 0):

[aiohttp-socks](https://github.com/romis2012/aiohttp-socks) has been updates again (while **aiosocksy** has been deprecated) so it should work on last python. as example shows:

```
async def fetch(url):
    connector = ProxyConnector.from_url('socks5://user:password@127.0.0.1:1080')
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()
```